# CIImage rendered to CVPixelBuffer (with CIContext help) changes color

Tags: ios, objective-c, ciimage, iosurface

I create a CIImage from an IOSurface. Then I render it to a CVPixelBuffer. If I skip the CIImage step the color is fine, however I intend to crop the image with CIImage/CIContext functions. However the problem is that the CIImage/CIContext step introduces color changes. See the example image, left is the intended colors and right is what I end up with.

[image]

I am pretty sure (although not certain) that it has to do with color spaces, and the fact that the iPhone uses a .. wide? .. color space? However I've tried countless of configurations, both in the CIContext and the render step. For example:

```
CIContext *cicontext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:@{
    kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: (id)CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceSRGB)
}];
```

And

```
[cicontext render:ciimage 
  toCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer 
           bounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1125, 2436) 
       colorSpace:CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceExtendedLinearSRGB)];
```

But I never get any different result. My full code is:

```
CIImage *ciimage = [CIImage imageWithIOSurface:surface];
CIContext *cicontext = [CIContext context];
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
NSDictionary *pixelAttributes = @{(id)kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                                  (id)kCVPixelBufferBytesPerRowAlignmentKey: @(16),
                                  (id)kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: (id)kCFBooleanTrue};
CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                    1125, 
                    2436, 
                    kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, 
                    (__bridge CFDictionaryRef _Nullable)(pixelAttributes),
                    &pixelBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
[cicontext render:ciimage 
  toCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer 
           bounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1125, 2436) 
       colorSpace:CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceExtendedLinearSRGB)];
[writerAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:presentTime];
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);    
CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);
CFRelease(surface);
```

And below are the NSLogs from the CIImage, CIContext, CVPixelBuffer, in case that helps. I have had configurations where I set the CIContext CGColorSpace to the same as the CIImage, without any change in output.
CIImage:

```
<CIImage: 0x28191cbf0 extent [0 0 1125 2436]>
<CGColorSpace 0x283f5c240> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
```

CIContext

```
<CIContext: 0x28191dff0 (metal 24) MTLDevice=0x104738000>
    priority: default
    workingSpace: <CGColorSpace 0x283f71500> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB Linear)
    workingFormat: RGBAh
    downsampleQuality: Low
```

Pixel Buffer

```
<CVPixelBuffer 0x282a7b2a0 width=1125 height=2436 bytesPerRow=4544 pixelFormat=BGRA iosurface=0x0 attributes={
    BytesPerRowAlignment = 16;
    CGBitmapContextCompatibility = 1;
    CGImageCompatibility = 1;
    PixelFormatDescription =     {
        BitsPerBlock = 32;
        BitsPerComponent = 8;
        BlackBlock = {length = 4, bytes = 0x000000ff};
        CGBitmapContextCompatibility = 1;
        CGBitmapInfo = 8196;
        CGImageCompatibility = 1;
        ComponentRange = FullRange;
        ContainsAlpha = 1;
        ContainsGrayscale = 0;
        ContainsRGB = 1;
        ContainsYCbCr = 0;
        FillExtendedPixelsCallback = {length = 24, bytes = 0x00000000000000008cfcbea8010000000000000000000000};
        IOSurfaceCoreAnimationCompatibility = 1;
        IOSurfaceOpenGLESFBOCompatibility = 1;
        IOSurfaceOpenGLESTextureCompatibility = 1;
        OpenGLESCompatibility = 1;
        PixelFormat = 1111970369;
    };
} propagatedAttachments={
} nonPropagatedAttac
```

Comment: This is obj-c right?

Comment: Have you tried passing `NULL` instead of `CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceSRGB)`?

Comment: Also, CVPixelBuffer can be BGRA, not RGBA

Comment: @aheze This is obj-c, yes.

Comment: @Olha, right. I have tried using `kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: [NSNull null]` in the `CIContext` as well. And the `CVPixelBuffer` I have tried both `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` and `kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA`

Comment: I've fixed a very similar problem some time ago, but unfortunately I can't guess anything more for this code. What I could advice: 1) double-check the metadata of the input file (e.g. `exiftool` on MacOS). It can be 16-bit/SomeSpecificColorSpace etc 2) post a minimal reproducible example on Github, with input image linked - then I'll try to look at it.

Comment: The input is an IOSurface that is linked to the display itself, so I suppose the CIImage is the closest I get to the input. Or the IOSurface itself, which has the pixel format CV30RgbLePackedWideGamut. Not sure if that helps.
I will _try_ to make a minimal example, but the code runs outside of the sandbox and doesn't work in sandbox app (and the color problem is not present in simulator). But I'll try, either way I appreciate the offer.